# Is it possible to change the id of a row?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate

When a user insert a new row into a SharePoint list. That row will be copied into another list with Power Automate.

Only the id of the rows are different. Is it possible to change the id of a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the SharePoint default `ID` column in list.

Instead you can follow below steps, assuming you already have a Power automate flow running on item creation in 1st list (`List A`):

1. Create a new column in 2nd list, say `ListAItemID`.
2. In "Create item" action which is used to create item in 2nd list, you can set `ListAItemID` column with dynamic content (`ID`) from 1st list like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is possible, it isn't wise to change the internal ID of a SharePoint object.  You should make an additional column with a "ReferenceID" or something.  Just use that when you need to cross connect the 2 lists.

Comment: So it is possible to create another column in list2 with the id of the row of list 1 ?

Comment: I have done it on prem.  I can't imagine why not online.  I even had it link back to the original list item.

Comment: Can you show me how? gr. p

Comment: Maybe similar to this.  I don't have a way to show you. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-Specific-Item-from-a-SharePoint-List-based-on-a-value-in/td-p/46266